# System.out.println doesn't show package name

Tags: java, android, push-notification, package, println

I am trying to get an application ID from an app.

My final goal is getting push messages to it. But I can't figure out why my package name doesn't show up.
Does someone have an solution for it?
Or an example app where it is working on?

This is my code I used for getting my package name:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ClassA instanceOfClass = new ClassA();
    String packageName = instanceOfClass.getClass().getPackage().getName();
    System.out.println( "Package Name : " + packageName);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

Comment: Where do you look for the printed string ?

Comment: just use Log.d(TAG,MSG) instead of System.out.println() and look for it in the logcat

Comment: I have a simulator and just in de app where "Hello World" shows up

Comment: May be you set other output strem?

Comment: @CodingBird So it will be this: Log.d("PackageName: ", packageName); ?

Comment: If you want the package name of the current class, you could use this.getClass().getPackage().getName();.

Comment: It should be: Log.d("ANY_STRING", "Package Name: "+packageName); Here ANY_STRING can be any string you want, it's just a tag that will be used to find your debugging log in the logcat :)

Comment: Check your logcat, I tested for my phone and it shows in the logcat

Comment: It doesn't show up in my logcat...

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in the Java package name or the Android package name? In the general case, they may be different.
An Activity has [getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getPackageName%28%29) defined in the ancestor class ContextWrapper and documented as: *Return the name of this application's package.*

Comment: I am intrested in the android one

Comment: Then use getPackageName()

Answer (score 0):

Use the code without the instance of the class
i.e `String packageName = getClass().getPackage()
                .getName().toString();`
This 'll return you the current package name.